# Possible causes for getting a javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException error in WebSphere?

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, websphere, webservice-client

This is an old system, we are using

WebSphere 6.0
Java 1.4

We have a jsp within which there is web service call to a web service deployed on WebSphere 6.0.  I am getting the following in the stack trace.  Could anyone tell me what could be the reason?  Thank you.

```
[9/30/16 17:20:16:258 CDT] 00000038 SystemOut     O  INFO LoginUser:47 - AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bx.a(bx.java:77)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bx.b(bx.java:46)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.by.b(by.java:131)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.by.a(by.java:471)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.by.l(by.java:329)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.by.startHandshake(by.java:446)
    at org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory.create(JSSESocketFactory.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.getSocket(HTTPSender.java:191)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.writeToSocket(HTTPSender.java:404)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender.invoke(HTTPSender.java:138)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:165)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at us.tx.state.dads.cm.service.SimpleDataRetrievalServiceSoapBindingStub.getPropertiesAsNamePairsByConfiguration(SimpleDataRetrievalServiceSoapBindingStub.java:82)
    at us.tx.state.dads.sessionservice.config.ConfigUtil.isSingleSignOnEnabled(ConfigUtil.java:109)
    at us.tx.state.dads.framework.session.login.LoginUser.isSingleSignOnEnabled(LoginUser.java:43)
    at com.ibm._jsp._main._jspService(_main.java:155)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:93)
```

Comment: Looks like you are consuming a HTTPS web service,. You will need to import the certificate and keys for that to successfully handshake. You could look at doing a Retrieve From Port (http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_sslretrievesignersport.html) to do this as well , HTH

Comment: THe server sent a handshake_failure alert.  You need to debug this on the server side.